# Why doesn't redis-server work inside my docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to deploy my node app using docker to AWS(elasticbeanstalk).

When I just deploy my node app, it works fine, but I'm confused with connecting elasticache redis.

In the local test, redis-server works with my app, but inside the docker container not.

It only works when composing multi-container(node,redis).

I don't know why redis not work inside docker container and I need help how to connect docker to elasticache redis in the ec2.

Comment: Can you connect to redis docker from local?

Comment: yes redis-server from local. not elasticache redis. How can i connect elasticache redis?